# simple postfix configuration - forward all incoming email to single address

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, gmail

I've a Ubuntu 9.04 server installation which is hosting a small number of websites (currently two, and will remain in single figures).  The email requirements for the  server are very limited - to send outgoing emails and forward all incoming emails to a mailbox on another server - most likely Google.

I've installed postfix and the outgoing mail is working fine.  How do I configure Postfix to forward all incoming mail?  If I send it to a googlemail address are there any special considerations?  Finally how difficult is it to incorporate basic spam filtering into the forwarding mechanism?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is called a "catch all"

Mapping is done using /etc/postfix/virtual file.

```
vi /etc/postfix/virtual
```

Append code as follows, replacing domain and emailusername with actual values:

```
@yourdomain.com emailusername
```

Save and close the file. Run following command:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
```

Also make sure you have following line in /etc/postfix/main.cf file:

```
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

If you just added above, line reload postfix:

```
service postfix reload
```

From http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-postfix-catch-all-email-accounts/

Comment: Brilliant stuff.  This helped me too.  Thanks Matt!

Answer (score 5):

You need [virtual aliases](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html). Something like:

```
virtual_alias_domains = foo.com, bar.com
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

where `/etc/postfix/virtual` contains:

```
@foo.com    you@gmail.com
@bar.com    you@gmail.com
```

run `postmap /etc/postfix/virtual` to create the database from the map file and `postfix reload` to re-read the configuration. The virtual table is quite flexible -- you can match specific addresses or whole domains and forward mail to multiple addresses.

Note: Do **not** list the extra domains in `$mydestination`! See the docs for more detail.

No special considerations I can think of when sending to GMail addresses. One optional neat trick is to send mail for each domain to a separate address and have GMail automatically label it accordingly. Forward mail for `foo.com` to `you+foo.com@gmail.com` and `bar.com` to `you+bar.com@gmail.com` and corresponding filters. See this [GMail blog post](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html) for more.

I haven't tried but one method to filter spam is to incorporate SpamAssassin. A Google for this turns up quite a few handy-looking guides.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simpler to use 'always_bcc = name@domain.com' in main.cf?
Denes

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using [virtual aliases](http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL%5FREADME.html) or mail forwarding, Postfix tends to retain the envelope sender from the original message. This causes problems for Gmail and others that use SPF:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning ***@***.com does not
    designate *** as permitted sender);
```

I haven't found any good solution for this, but here's a hack to sort-of-fix-it:

1. Create a new file `/etc/postfix/sender_canonical`:

   ```
   /.*/    postmaster
   ```
2. `postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical`
3. Add some lines to `/etc/postfix/main.cf`:

   ```
   sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender
   sender_canonical_maps = regexp:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
   ```
4. `service postfix reload`
5. Send email from an external source and verify that `Return-Path` contains your `postmaster@***` address

**Warning:** This **replaces the envelope sender for all messages** passing through your server, which may have unintended side-effects. The message `From` headers should not be modified by this however, so sender addresses should still display correctly.

Comment: How to configure sender_canonical to set a "From", I need to forward all incoming email using static email in "From" header, it is because I am using a relay that only can send email from the only email which are added there.