# Configuring Mail Relay

Tags: postfix, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I'm running Ubuntu Server 9.10 with Postfix and Webmin.

I have created virtual hosts for 3 domains following [this serverfault.com answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/49044/simple-postfix-configuration-forward-all-incoming-email-to-single-address).

But the mail isn't relaying out to the world. I have 3 domains tied into my DNS in webmin, as well as inside DNS clicked Mail Server and followed that instruction [using this article on the web](http://www.sambahosting.com/forums/showthread.php?p=222).

The domains and the web servers work just fine. I also have FTP working just fine. So, the remaining problem I have is mail. Can't forward mail out to a Gmail account for some reason. Note I'm just trying to do the "easy version" of Postfix config and if your answer is in Webmin-ease, that would help me. However, I can edit a text file if you suggest.

I was asked to include some /var/log/mail.log stuff, so here it is:

```
May 24 16:43:26 uc6 postfix/smtpd[432]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-gy0-f176.google.com[209.85.160.176]: 554 5.7.1 <support@example.com>: Relay access denied; from=<testacct@gmail.com> to=<support@example.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail-gy0-f176.google.com>
```

Also, looks like I'm getting hit by random port scanners trying to look for open relays:

(note I changed my IP address below to 55.55.55.55 for privacy)

```
May 24 13:40:54 uc6 postfix/smtpd[29311]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from 123-204-7-37.dynamic.seed.net.tw[123.204.7.37]: 554 5.7.1 <sseenndd0101@yahoo.com.hk>: Relay access denied; from=<h6koo9b46u@yahoo.com.tw> to=<sseenndd0101@yahoo.com.hk> proto=SMTP helo=<55.55.55.55>
```

Comment: To start with, why not post your maillog so we can see what kind of error you get when you try to relay a mail to google.

Comment: did you check the logs in /var/log/mail.log, /var/log/user.log, /var/log/mail.info, /var/log/mail.warn, /var/log/mail.err ? 
easy to see them all, 
egrep -r '(mail|postfix):' /var/log

Comment: Okay, edited my original post, so look at that.

Comment: Note on the mail spam issue, I installed Postgrey as well as installed recommended Postfix tweaks, and the spam went away. But that's another thing for me to post separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. After setting up mail aliases in Webmin's Postfix module, I had to edit:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

And add in this line...

**virtual_alias_domains = example1.com example2.com**

...where exampel1.com and example2.com are 2 domains I want to forward mail on...

...added above this line...

**virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual**

I then had to run these commands:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/virtual
postfix reload
```

It then worked after that.

SOURCE: http://www.postfix.org/VIRTUAL_README.html (search for "relay access denied")