# Postfix not forwarding emails

Tags: linux, email, postfix, ubuntu-10.04

I followed the guide here: http://library.linode.com/email/postfix/gateway-ubuntu-10.04-lucid which has similar points to the question here [simple postfix configuration - forward all incoming email to single address](https://serverfault.com/questions/49044/simple-postfix-configuration-forward-all-incoming-email-to-single-address) but I'm still having problems.

I running Ubuntu on Linode and have several domains which I simply want to forward any email to those domains to a gmail account.

My virtual postfix file has the following:

```
@domain1.com email@gmail.com
@domain2.com email@gmail.com
@domain3.com email@gmail.com
```

My main.cf is exactly as in the guide:

```
myhostname = jamie.mydomain.com
mydestination = localhost, li1121-21.members.linode.com, localhost.members.linode.com, lochahost
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
home_mailbox = mail/
```

My FQDN (when I run `hostname -f`) is: `jamie.mydomain.com` and for the DNS records for mydomain.com I have an A record named `jamie` pointing to my IP address and an MX record named `jamie.mydomain.com` with priorty 0 as I also have other MX records.

All other domains that point to this IP address are setup with linode defaults, which is an A record called `mail` pointing to the IP address and an MX record named `mail.mydomain1.com`.

I feel like I have it setup as per the guide but whenever I send an email to any of the domains it just bounces.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact error in the mail log?

Comment: Where can I find the log?

Comment: Ok found the log.  It says "550 Failed: User does not exist".  Looks like it's trying to send to `root@jamie.mydomain.com`

Comment: should be /var/log/mail.log or similar

Comment: Interestingly, I have some entries in the mail.log that say messages were sent to the gmail account I have mapped in `virtual` but nothing has arrived, not in spam either

Comment: you need to post at least the contents of /etc/postfix/main.cf. Have you postmap'ed the virtual file and restartet postfix?

Comment: Have you done the postmap, dangit Tim.

Comment: Yes I did the postmap and restarted postfix

Comment: I just tried sending more mail and the log doesn't even update now, as if the mail isn't even reaching the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by completely removing all of sendmail and postfix and reinstalling.  I followed this guide exactly and it worked first time.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04

Still not sure what the original error was but I wanted to add an answer here just in case others come across this question.